# How do I solve this combinatorial proof involving factorial (n)_k?

Tags: proof-writing, factorial, combinatorial-proofs

> Let $n$ and $k$ be positive integers with $n \ge k$.
>   Give a combinatorial proof that $$n_k = (n-1)_k + k(n-1)_{k-1},$$ where $n_k$ is a falling factorial: $n_k$ = $n(n-1)(n-2)\ldots(n-k+1)$.

I know $n_k = n \cdot (n-1)_{k-1}$.
For example $10_4 = 10 \cdot 9_3$, which equates to: $10 \cdot 9 \cdot 8 \cdot 7 = 10 \cdot (9 \cdot 8 \cdot 7)$.

However, I am completely lost on how to extrapolate $n_k = (n-1)_k + k(n-1)_{k-1}$ from $n_k = n \cdot (n-1)_{k-1}$.

I can work out numerical examples in my head and it makes perfect sense, but I'm missing something and I dont know what it is that I'm missing.

Comment: Hint: Split the $n$ factor into $\left(n-k\right) + k$.

Answer (score 2):

$n_k$ represents the number of arrangements of $n$ elements in groups of $k$ (the order is relevant here). Split those arrangements into two classes: those where one particular element is part of the group and those where this element is not part of the group. The number of the latter is $(n-1)_k$ because you choose among the rest. The number of the former is $k(n-1)_{k-1}$ because you choose $k-1$ among the remaining $(n-1)$ and there are $k$ possible locations for the fixed element.

Comment: I thought you were supposed to give a combinatorial proof, not an algebraic one.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the notation which you have used(I am still new in combinatorics). So I will use simple factorial notation. 
$$\frac{n!}{(n-k)!}$$
$$=\frac{{((n-k)+k)}\cdot{(n-1)!}}{(n-k)!}$$
$$=\frac{(n-1)!}{(n-k-1)!}+\frac{k(n-1)!}{(n-k)!}$$
$$=(n-1)_k +k(n-1)_{k-1}$$